# $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{e^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{e^n}{n!}$$
I am pretty sure already it converges, I'm trying to find to what.
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{e^n}{n!}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\prod^n_{j=1}\frac{e}{j}$$
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sum^\infty_{j=0}\frac{n^j}{j!}}{n!}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^\infty_{j=0}\frac{n^j}{n!j!}=\sum^\infty_{j=0}\frac{1}{j!}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{n^j}{n!}$$
from here, i have no idea.

Comment: what's the taylor expansion of $e^x$?

Comment: I'll try. thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain a proof for the expansion of $\exp x$? If yes, then tell me. If no, then remember it; the series you're talking about is the expansion of $e^x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will use the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) fromula:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
This formula converges to the value of the function if and only if the function is analytic in an open disk centered at 0.
Now, let $f(x)=e^x$. We know that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^x=e^x\quad \forall n\ge0$$
so that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^x\bigg\rvert_{0}=e^0=1$$
Substituting this in the original Taylor series formula yields
\begin{align}
e^x&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^x\big\rvert_{0}}{n!}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align}
Substituting $x=e$ gives
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^n}{n!}=e^e\approx15.142622$$

Comment: Can you give the assumptions with which the formula "$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$" holds ? It is definitely not true for every function $f$, the series may diverge or not be equal to $f(x)$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe did it. Please check if I am right.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but this is still not right :) Even if the radius of convergence is $+\infty$, the series can be not equal to the function... Consider $f = \exp(-x)$ if $x > 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \leq 0$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe sorry, I didn't realize it. Now I updated it and I am almost sure that it's true.

Comment: Ok, now this is correct ! Even if one should ask why $\exp$ is analytic ;) But I upvote your answer, thanks for takinf the time of correcting.